# How to build Python poker card game : In between or Acey Duecy - python lists

Tags: python, list

I am making this python terminal text running poker card game called *"In between"* or *"Acey Duecy"*.
I have tried but I am not the best with `lists` and I don't know how to assign a value in the `list` a number (1-13) so that when they try and guess the card in between I can use `<` or `>`.

Here is what my code looks like right now. I just need help building the functions. By the way I'm pretty sure some of my other functions are wrong too. Correct me if I am wrong. Thanks for all your help

```py
# this is mocking the poker game in between, also known as acey ducey
# no need for graphics, its just text based
# IMPORT MODULE(S)

import random

# VARIABLES
bank = 1000
initbank = bank
name = ""
pot = 2000
initpot = pot
cardcount = 52
highcard = 0 # range is 0-12 but, the ace can be 13 in value
lowcard = 0 # Don't forget to put the cards in order
bet = 0
thirdcard = 0
keepplaying = False
response = ""
cardname = ["ACE","TWO","THREE","FOUR","FIVE","SIX","SEVEN","EIGHT","NINE","TEN","JACK","QUEEN","KING"]
suit = [ "OF CLUBS","OF DIAMONDS","OF HEARTS","OF SPADES"]
deck = []
for n in range(4):
    for i in range(13):
        all_card = (cardname[i] + " " + suit[n])
        deck.append(all_card)

# FUNCTION DECLARATIONS
def initdeck(deck):
    random.shuffle(deck)

def swapit(lownum, highnum):
    pass

def getacard(deck, cardcount):
    print("Here are your 2 cards.")
    print(*deck[:2], sep=', ')
    bet_card = deck[2]
    #deck.pop(0) - pop the cards after the round is done
    #deck.pop(0) - pop the cards after the round is done
    #deck.pop(0) - pop the cards after the round is done
    cardcount -= 3

def oneace(lowcard, highcard):
    pass

def getaplay(deck, cardcount):
    pass

def getbet(pot, bank):
    pass_bet = str(input("Would you like to pass your bet? | Y or N: ")).lower()
    yes = "y"
    no = "n"
    if pass_bet == yes:
        print("You have passed your bet")
    elif pass_bet == no:
        print("How much would you like to bet? ")
        print("The highest you can bet is", bank, "since that is how much you have in your bank")
        bet_amount = int(input("Enter your bet: "))
        if bet_amount > pot or bet_amount > bank:
            print("You cant bet that much")
            bet_amount = int(input("Enter amount you would like to bet: "))
        elif bet_amount <= pot or bet_amount <= bank:
            pot = pot + bet_amount
            bank = bank - bet_amount
            give_bet = True

def playthehand(deck, cardcount, lowcard, highcard, pot, bank): # show the hidden card??
    pass

def checkresult(lowcard, playcard, highcard, bet, pot, bank): # check to see if the bet was won or no, if the third card is in the middle of the two drawn
    pass
```

If it makes it easier this a some of the code on how the game would run WITHOUT functions and with more comments :

```
import random

bank = 1000
initbank = bank
name = ""
pot = 2000
initpot = pot
cardcount = 52
highcard = 0 # range is 0-12 but, the ace can be 13 in value
lowcard = 0 # Don't forget to put the cards in order
bet = 0
thirdcard = 0
keepplaying = False
response = ""
cardname = ["ACE","TWO","THREE","FOUR","FIVE","SIX","SEVEN","EIGHT","NINE","TEN","JACK","QUEEN","KING"]
suit = [ "OF CLUBS","OF DIAMONDS","OF HEARTS","OF SPADES"]
deck = []
for n in range(4):
    for i in range(13):
        all_card = (cardname[i] + " " + suit[n])
        deck.append(all_card)

###################################################
print("Welcome to Wedges...")
random.shuffle(deck)
print("You have", bank , "in your bank to start")
print("Guess if the third card is in between the two shown below.")
print("If the third card is the same value as either two card its called a goal post and the cards are removed")
print("Here are your options")
print("1 - If you think there is a slight chance, bet the minimum which is 1")
print("2 - If you think there is a huge chance, bet from as low as 1 -", bank)
print("3 - If you would not like to bet, you can pass ")
#################################
# if first_card == second_card :
    # deck.pop(0)
    # deck.pop(0)
# else :
    #pass
# game starts when cards are handed out
first_card = deck[0]
second_card = deck[1]
third_card = deck[2] # third card technically
print("Here are your 2 cards.")
print(first_card, " ? ", second_card)
#deck.pop(0) - pop the cards after the round is done
#deck.pop(0) - pop the cards after the round is done
#deck.pop(0) - pop the cards after the round is done
cardcount -= 3
#################################
# wanna bet or no
print("After seeing your card, would you like to bet or no?")
wanna_bet = int(input("1 - I wanna bet | 0 - I don't wanna bet: "))
no = 0
yes = 1
if wanna_bet == yes :
    print("Is the third card in between ? Bet big if you think yes, Bet medium if you think maybe")
    if bank > pot :
        print("The most you can bet is", pot )
    elif bank < pot :
        print("The most you can bet is", bank )
    bet = int(input("Enter the amount you would like to bet: "))
    if bet > bank or bet > pot :
        bet = int(input("Enter the amount you would like to bet: "))
    elif bet <= bank or bet <= pot and bet != 0 :
        bet_entered = True # take this out when u make it in a function
elif wanna_bet == no :
    pass
    bet_entered = False
    # deal next cards # start new round

if bet_entered == True :
    print("The third card was", third_card)
    # if third card is between first card and second card take bet amount from pot, add to bank
    # if third card is NOT between first card and second card, take bet amount from bank, add to pot
    #####################
    # sample code
    # if third_card > first_card and third_card < second_card and third_card != first_card and third_card != second_card:
        # bank = bank + bet
        # pot = pot - bet
    # elif third_card <= first_card and third_card <= second_card or third_card >= first_card and third_card >= second_card or third_card == first_card or third_card == second_card :
        # bank = bank - bet
        # pot = pot + bet
elif bet_entered == False :
    pass
    # run the game again from beggeing and deal cards
```

Comment: I've removed the [tag:pygame] tag. The [tag:pygame] tag addresses the [PyGame](https://www.pygame.org/news) library, but is not intended for a game written in Python.